# What is an Ethereum address?

Tags: accounts, addresses

I am being asked to enter my Ethereum address, but I don't know what to put there and I already created an Ethereum account.

Comment: When you find your address, and come to enter it, try not to enter it by hand. If you can, copy+paste it. That way you'll lower the chances of making a mistake.

Comment: Would you clarify how your account was created, e.g. from a particular client (geth, parity, etc.), or from an exchange, or hardware wallet, etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Ethereum address** is a sequence of 20 bytes which are calculated from public key by performing this algorithm:

```
addr=right(keccak256(pubkey),20)
```

After the computation, addresses basically look like this:

> 0x09438E46Ea66647EA65E4b104C125c82076FDcE5